# Error CS0563 (One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type)

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, instantiation

My source code (below) is generating Error CS0563 because both of the parameters in my CombinedJobs operator+ (see "//Step 5: ..." in source code) are listed as Job (as opposed to int, double, etc). How can I change this code to eliminate this error? This code is in response to the assignment listed below.

Assignment:

"Design a Job class for Harold’s Home Services. The class contains four data fields—Job
description (for example, “wash windows”), time in hours to complete the Job (for
example, 3.5), per-hour rate charged for the Job (for example, $25.00), and total fee for
the Job (hourly rate times hours). Include properties to get and set each field except
the total fee—that field will be read-only, and its value is calculated each time either
the hourly fee or the number of hours is set. Overload the + operator so that two Jobs
can be added. The sum of two Jobs is a new Job containing the descriptions of both
original Jobs ( joined by “and”), the sum of the time in hours for the original Jobs, and
the average of the hourly rate for the original Jobs. Write a Main()function that
demonstrates all the methods work correctly. Save the file as DemoJobs.cs."

From: Microsoft® Visual C#® 2008, An Introduction to Object-Oriented Programming, 3e, Joyce Farrell

Source Code:

```
using System;

//Step 1: Creating the Job class and designating its fields

   public class Job

   {

      private string jobDescription;

      private int jobTotalTime;

      private double jobRate;

      private double jobTotalFee;


//Step 2: Using the 'this' object will allow me to designate values for 

//"this" instantiation of an object later in the program

      public string JobDescription
      {
         get
         {
            return this.jobDescription;
         }
         set
         {
            this.jobDescription = value;
         }
      }  

      public int JobTotalTime
      {
         get
         {
            return this.jobTotalTime;
         }
         set
         {
            this.jobTotalTime = value;
         }
      }  

     public double JobRate
      {
         get
         {
            return this.jobRate;
         }
         set
         {
            this.jobRate = value;
         }
      }       

    public double JobTotalFee
      {
         get
         {
            return this.jobTotalFee;
         }
         set
         {
            this.jobTotalFee = this.JobRate * this.JobTotalTime;
         }
      }  

//Step 3: Creating a method will allow me to display the different jobs 

//with their descriptions and other variable fields later in the program

   public void JobMessage()

   {

      Console.WriteLine("Job description: {0} /nTotal time needed to complete the job: {1} hours /nHourly fee: ${2} /nTotal fee for the job is: ${3}", this.JobDescription, this.JobTotalTime, this.JobRate, this.JobTotalFee);

   }


}

//Step 4: Creating two instantiations of the Job Class

public class CreateTwoJobs

{

   public static void Main()

   {

   Job jobA = new Job();

   Job jobB = new Job();


   jobA.JobDescription = "washing windows";

   jobA.JobTotalTime = 5;

   jobA.JobRate = 25.00;


   jobB.JobDescription = "walking dogs";

   jobB.JobTotalTime = 10;

   jobB.JobRate = 11.00;


   jobA.JobMessage();

   jobB.JobMessage();

   }

}


//Step 5: Creating a third instantiation of the Job Class that is a combination 

//of the first two instantiations using the overloaded + operator


public class CombinedJobs

{

   public CombinedJobs(string jobDescription, int jobTotalTime, double jobRate, double jobTotalFee)

   {

   JobDescription = jobDescription;

   JobTotalTime = jobTotalTime;

   JobRate = jobRate;

   JobTotalFee = jobTotalFee;

   }


   public static CombinedJobs operator+(Job jobA, Job jobB)

   {

   string newDescription = jobA.JobDescription + " and " + jobB.JobDescription;

   int newTotalTime = jobA.JobTotalTime + jobB.JobTotalTime;

   double newJobRate = (jobA.JobRate + jobB.JobRate) / 2;

   double newTotalFee = newJobRate * newTotalTime

   }


   public void CombinedJobMessage()

   {

      Console.WriteLine("Job description: {0} /nTotal time needed to complete the job: {1} hours /nHourly fee: ${2} /nTotal fee for the job is: ${3}", newDescription, newTotalTime, newJobRate, newTotalTime);

   }   


   public static void Main()

   {

      CombinedJobMessage();

   }

}
```

Comment: The setter of JobTotalFee is **EVIL**. And your code would be a lot shorter if you used auto properties. I'd use `public double JobTotalFee { get {return this.JobRate * this.JobTotalTime;}};` with no backing field at all. But your assignment requires that you set the backing field in the setters of JobRate and JobTotalTime. No idea why.

Answer (score 5):

The `operator+` method has to be inside the class of one of its parameters. Since in your case both parameters are `Job`, the method has to be inside the `Job` class. It can't be inside `CombinedJobs`.

Also, you declared the operator as returning `CombinedJobs`, so that means you have to actually return it. This is not causing the error you are describing, but it would cause another compile error.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I've almost got this program in working order now. Just one thing left...